# Why folder gets deleted after rerun, nest.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, file, nestjs

I write project on MacOS sonoma using nest.js, and now I has this problem: I have product module and a folder `src/products/images` with images (.png, .jpg) of products. But after every project rerun(npm start) that image folder gets deleted.

I save images like this:

```js
for (const image of images) {
  const fileName: string = uuid.v4();
  const fileExtension: string = image.originalname.split(".").pop();
  const filePath: string = `${productImagesDir}/${
    fileName + "." + fileExtension
  }`;

  console.log(image);

  await fs.promises.copyFile(image.path, filePath);

  let productImage = this.productImageRepository.create({
    product: product,
    url: `http://localhost:5500/api/product/images/${fileName}.${fileExtension}`,
  });
  await this.productImageRepository.save(productImage);
  successFullyUploadedImages.push(productImage);
}
```

But after npm start, in "dist/product/" I have no folder "images". I tried add this in Product module:

```
MulterModule.register({
  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: "./src/product/images",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const uniqueSuffix: string = v4();
      const extension = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
      console.log(uniqueSuffix);
      console.log(extension);
      cb(null, `${uniqueSuffix}.${extension}`);
    },
  }),
});
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NestJS copy assets files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60385790/nestjs-copy-assets-files)

Answer (score 0):

Images file like .png or .jpg are assets. NestCLI ignores assets by default. If you want your NestCLI will copy assets into `/dist` you need change `nest-cli.json` config file.

I recommend checking out this answer on how to configure `nest-cli.json`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77009968/23268162